# Does private Ethereum blockchain like Quorum need ether?

Tags: ether, private-blockchain, quorum

Does private blockchain built on Ethereum like Quorum need/require ether? How will the emergence of such private blockchains impact ether's value.

Answer (score 1):

Private Ethereum blockchains need Ether for transaction gas, but they require Ether that is mined on those networks. You cannot send ETH from one network to another. Thus, private Ethereum blockchains will not affect the price of mainnet ETH.